How to delay/pause/sleep on boot screen?
I'm using raspberry pi5 with debian bookworm.
I created a bash script and execute it on bootscreen.
The script has 100 seconds delay in it but no effect in boot screen.
The OS starts like there were no delay in that script but my script started to run.
My purpose is pausing system while on bootscreen...
Here is my bash script...
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/home/cnc/Desktop/brt.txt"

echo "A $(date)" >> "$LOGFILE"
sleep 100
echo "B $(date)" >> "$LOGFILE"

Here is my service file for running script on bootscreen
[Unit]
Description=My Sleep Script
After=systend-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/cnc/Desktop/sleepScript.sh

After bootscreen passes I checked my log file and only saw first line like;
A Mon Oct 14 16:32:59 +03 2024

but after a while ( and that's 100 seconds after the start of the program ) I rechecked my log file and I saw the second line there...
A Mon Oct 14 16:32:59 +03 2024
B Mon Oct 14 16:34:39 +03 2024

My purpose is, as I written before, pausing the system for a certaion period of time during on bootscreen.
In my second scenario completely prevent the system from booting up....
